# Given a dataset of geolocations, what is the best way to cluster and visualize them in python?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, data-science

i am new to this, i have a dataframe of street address and geolocation of events occured, i would like to cluster the values to get the most dense areas where events occured and visualize them as shape values on a map (folium generated)
What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plotly` to visualise the dataset on a map. Checkout [plotly](https://plot.ly/python/maps/) examples.

Answer (score 0):

I think for your case folium will be best

Check the Github page of the [folium](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium). You can find lots of examples in there

Here is quick start guide: https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html